# Problem on MoveIt after I Add Imu into it

Tags: ros, quadcopter, imu, rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i launch MoveIt and Add Imu into it, I found that:
Status: Error
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
For frame [fcu]: Frame [fcu] does not exist

Here is the link which i screenshot for the problem which i faced:
[http://imgur.com/a/kdTU1](https://imgur.com/a/kdTU1)

Hopefully, somebody help me to solve this kind of problem, Thank You so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238717/problem-on-moveit-after-i-add-imu-into-it/) by [Envo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26517/envo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your IMU publishes it's data with the frame_id set to `fcu`. There appears to be no connection to that frame in your current tf tree, however. You'll probably want to add the fcu frame to your robot URDF or run a `static_transform_publisher` to publish the transform (see for instance here: http://answers.ros.org/question/82931/failed-to-rosrun-static-tf-publisher/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0